# Proof that an ordinal number does not contain itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Hrbacek and Jech gives the following definition for ordinal numbers:
[image]

However, the following proof seems to rely on the fact that an ordinal number does not contain itself (argument circled in red).
[image]

It isn't clear to me why the red circle is true. Why is it clear that an ordinal does not contain itself?

Comment: The circled fact is trivially true regardless of choice of alpha. There is no need to invoke the fact that no ordinal contains itself.

Comment: Is the question about the fact that the containment is proper? Are you actually using this?

Answer (score 0):

No set (including an ordinal) is permitted to include itself due to the Axiom of regularity.

Comment: Yes. But this is not the point. The result is true without assuming foundation. The point is that ordinals are well-founded regardless of whether the axiom is assumed. This is useful information to know, and simply appealing to foundation hides its relevance.

Comment: That's true but the definition that is given for ordinal should be state that should be should be strict well ordered rather then just well ordered. As in an anti-foundational FAS there is a distinction between well founded and strictly well founded.

Comment: There is no distinction in the text: well-ordered is in the strict sense. What is FAS?

Comment: FAS = formal axiomatic system

Comment: How does the text define ”transitive set”? In particular, are Quine atoms ($a=\{a\}$) transitive in that definition?